# Network Connectivity Issue: Unable to Ping two VMs on eth1

Tags: linux, network-interface, ip, ping, router

I've configured two VMs and assigned them to the eth0 and to the eth1 interface.
However, I'm encountering connectivity issues as I'm unable to ping between two VMs using eth1. I've verified the network configuration for eth1 is correct, and the VMs can successfully communicate when using eth0.

The firewall is disabled on both VMs.

vm1:

```
# ip addr show
eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:16:3e:00:00:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.1/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:16:3e:00:00:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.16.1.100/24 brd 172.16.1.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

```
# ip route show
default via 192.168.0.7 dev eth0 
172.16.1.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 172.16.1.100 
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.1 
192.168.0.3 via 192.168.0.7 dev eth0 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.2
```

```
# ping 172.16.1.1
PING 172.16.1.1 (172.16.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

router_vm1:

```
# ip addr show
eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:16:3e:00:00:07 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.7/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:16:3e:00:00:08 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.16.1.1/24 brd 172.16.1.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

```
# ip route show
default via 192.168.0.254 dev eth0 
172.16.1.0/24 via 172.16.1.1 dev eth1 
172.16.1.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 172.16.1.1 
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.7 
192.168.0.1 via 192.168.0.7 dev eth0
```

```
# ping 172.16.1.100
PING 172.16.1.100 (172.16.1.100): 56 data bytes
```

I need assistance to find solutions to enable proper network communication between two VMs on eth1.

Comment: what type of VM are thoses ? (they don't seems to be vmware) How are VM's ethX related to host's ethX ? do you have multiple hosts ? If thoses VM are provided by either AWS (EC2), Azur or GCP, there is probably some more network configuration to do.

Comment: Both vm1 and router_vm1 are running on x86_64 architecture with a single KVM processor, and XEN is the hypervisor vendor. In the network scans, vm1 discovered two hosts with IP addresses 172.16.1.1 and 172.16.1.100, while router_vm1 found eight hosts with IP addresses in the 192.168.0.0/24 range and two hosts in the 172.16.1.0/24 range with MAC addresses